# How to disable a ladda button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Ladda UI for bootstrap.

Using jquery I try to disable a button after the user clicks on it.

I tried to use ajax OnComplete / OnSuccess / OnBegin , but no avail - the button remains enabled.

If I change the markup manually on firebug - I can disable it. Also note the js fires for sure.

**Here's the markup:**

```
<a id="icalSync" href="/iCal/iCalCreatedLinks" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-complete="AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton" data-ajax="true" data-style="expand-left" class="btn ladda-button">
<span class="ladda-label">Sync iCal</span>
<span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
</a>
```

**Here's the js function:**

```
function AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton() {
    $("#icalSync").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Since `a` elements does not have any `disabled` attribute, this won't work... Either change your element to a `button`, `input` or add a CSS rule to mimic the disabled state by some class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disable is not valid with anchor tags, so you could try this:

```
 function AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton() {
event.preventDefault();
 }
```

or change your could your a#icalSync to a button and use your code

```
<button id="icalSync" href="/iCal/iCalCreatedLinks" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-complete="AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton" data-ajax="true" data-style="expand-left" class="btn ladda-button">
<span class="ladda-label">Sync iCal</span>
<span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
</button>
```

or you could add the class disabled, used in bootstrap:

```
function AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton() { $("#icalSync").addClass("disabled"); }
```

Comment: The problem is that I use asp.net-MVC and the `@Ajax.ActionLink` produces an anchor tag... so I will make a button. I wish I could use some technique that would save me the change of the actionlink approach.

Comment: You can set an anchor to disabled in bootstrap by adding the class "disabled". ``function AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton() {
    $("#icalSync").addClass("disabled");
}

Comment: Yes ! this is the answer. Would be great if you write this in your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your "button" is not truly a button. You need to approach it differently. Either make it a `<button>` or in `AjaxOnCompleteDisableButton` assign it a class that will make it look like it's disabled (say opacity: 0.5) and ignore the triggering events on it.